# How to convert a bunch of images to black and white with overwritting existing ones?

Tags: linux, image-processing, command-line, imagemagick, ubuntu-16.04

I need to convert a bunch of images (about 1000) to black and white I used the following code:

```
convert *.bmp -monochrome ./*.bmp
```

but it produces new images. for example, I have file1.bmp, file2.bmp and etc. and it converts them to file1-1.bmp file2-2.bmp and so on. I need the exact same name for images so I prefer to overwrite the existing one. any suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: Use `mogrify` instead of `convert`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
mogrify -monochrome *.bmp
```

Note that this old v6 syntax to match your `convert`.

Modern v7 syntax would be:

```
magick mogrify -monochrome *.bmp
```